# Doctrine не поддгружает связанные обьекты

Tags: php, doctrine2

Например у меня есть таблицы campaigns и campaign_channels, я создаю обьект Campaign и CampaignChannels, в базе создаются воответствующие записи, но когда я хочу вытянуть из Campaign CampaignChannels то получаю пустую коллекцию.
даже так проверил:

```
dump(self::$campaign->getId());
dump($campaignChannel->getId());
dump(count(self::$campaign->getChannels()));
```

И посмотрел в базе, такие записи там точно есть, но count(self::$campaign->getChannels() показывает 0 записей

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, поддержание актуальности коллекций в процессе создания новых сущностей - Ваша ответственность.

Пример:

```
class CampaignChannel {
  /* ... */
  public function __construct(Campaign $campaign) {
    $this->campaign = $campaign;
    $campaign->getChannels()->add($this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Но даже если я выбираю из базы запросом уже после создания, то все равно пусто